# In C++ Output Parameter vs Return Value

Tags: c++

What is/are the difference(s) between output parameters and return values?  I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find a simple definition for either.

Comment: In case of `int foo(int& res /*this is output parameter*/) { return 1 /*this is return value*/; }`

Comment: Strictly speaking there is no such thing as "output parameter" in C++. You can use a pointer or reference to implement that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The *return value* is something well defined in C++; for instance, `x` in `return x;` is the return value, whereas `int` in the function declaration `int myfunc()` is the return type.
- The concpet of *output parameters* is not defined in C++. However someone would interpret it as either of the following:

  - *function parameters passed by non-`const` reference, as long as you actually modify it in the function*, otherwise why would you call it *output*? An example is `x` in the following function declaration: `void myfunc(int& x)`;
  - *function parameters passed by (not necessarily `const`) pointer to non-`const`*, like `x` in both the following function declarations: `void fun1(int * x)` and `void fun2(int * const x)`;

    - concerning this latter case, it allows "encoding" a missing parameter in as a `nullptr` default value, as in `void fun3(int * x = nullptr)`.

A first difference is aesthetic: which one you like the most?

Another one is that the former concept and syntax help you convey the message that the function is giving back a value, something which is clear at the call site too (whereas at the call site you might not know if a parameter corresponding to an argument is passed by reference or not).

[There are several differences](https://codeyarns.com/2010/10/21/c-return-value-versus-output-parameter/) between this two ways a function can have "consequences" at the caller site. For instance, you can only have **one** return value, whereas you can have as many parameters as you like.

Performancewise, complier optimizations can minimize the difference in performance, and maybe you should not worry (yet) about it.

Comment: You could also mention pointer, especially since there are legacy standard library functions which use that. Additionally, pointer allows passing `nullptr` (often set as detault argument im C++) if the value is not needed by the caller.